# C++ - Can you get only the variable name from a macro argument where you supply both a type and name?

Tags: c++, variables, types, macros, arguments

I'm attempting to create a `SendEvent` function within a macro where I am defining an event structure (I'm using a macro so people can supply a variable amount of arguments from 1-10 depending on how much data they want to use in their event structure). I will use the 3 argument macro as an example:

```
#define __MakeEvent3_(ID, t1_, t2_, t3_)                                                    \
struct S ## ID ## Event {                                                                   \
    RegisterEventRecords_(S ## ID ## Event);                                                \
    t1_;                                                                                    \
    t2_;                                                                                    \
    t3_;                                                                                    \
};                                                                                          \
typedef S ## ID ## Event SEvent;                                                            \
inline void Send ## ID ## Event(t1_, t2_, t3_) {                                            \
    SEvent evt;                                                                             \
    evt.t1_ = t1_;                                                                          \
    evt.t2_ = t2_;                                                                          \
    evt.t3_ = t3_;                                                                          \
    level->SendEvent(evt);                                                                  \
}
```

The macro is invoked where each `t1_`, `t2_`, etc. argument has both a type and a name, and depending on the amount of args supplied, the master macro will resolve to use the given `__MakeEventN_()`:

```
MakeSystemEvent_(Player, int playernum, MessageType msgtype, char* msg) // invokes __MakeEvent3()_
```

The problem is I don't know of a way to access the *name* of the variable (i.e., `playernum`) given just the argument `t1_`, since that contains the value `int playernum`. The result of this is that, not surprisingly, I get multiple compiler errors when assigning `evt.t1_ = t1_`, since its not even a viable statement of syntax.

Is there any solution for parsing out the type of a macro argument that has both variable type and name in order to get just the variable name?

Comment: You can have a type-safe variable number of arguments with variadic templates in C++11, which was the same time variadic macros were standardized.

Comment: Perhaps consider a slightly different approach, e.g. just have the user define their own struct and make your code have templates which can accept whatever the user provides

Comment: Depends on what you mean 'get the name'. If you want the name as a C-string, just use `# t1_`. If you want the name of the argument passed in - that's not possible. It might be a numeric value, or an expression, or other item. In your example creating the `SEvent` structure, how will _t1 pass both a name and a value to assign?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__MakeEvent3_`, `__MakeEventN_`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm confused about that - you say they are reserved for implementation, but thats what I'm using them for isn't it? The only macro that other people should be using is the `MakeSystemEvent_` macro, all of the ones that I have with two consecutive underscores are essentially internal macros that other users should never touch.

Comment: @Blindleistung the question explains it pretty well I thought, but I'm looking for the variable name of the two-word argument `t1_` (example: `int playernum`). I'm trying to parse just the word `playernum` so that I can do exactly what you are pointing out won't work correctly in your comment.

Comment: @WilliamDewayneCorrinIII — they’re reserved for use by **the** implementation. The standard uses that term to refer to the compiler, linker, standard libraries, etc.

Comment: @PeteBecker ah, okay well thank you that is good to know. I tend to like using that formatting when wrapping macros inside of macros so that users know which ones to invoke and which ones aren't meant to be used outside of the file with the macros in it.